# Kerberos Method on Oracle 5.11

Tags: linux, samba

When running 'sudo net ads join -U admin' to add my domain to the realm, I get the error: Unknown parameter encountered: "kerberos method"

I found out that 'kerberos method' is not supported by samba 3.4  (I have 3.0), but I can't upgrade to it to, I believe because I am running Oracle Linux 5.11.

Is there a way to get a similar functionality as 'kerberos method = secrets and keytabs'?

If not, which version of Oracle Linux would I have to upgrade to in order to get samba 3.4?

Comment: Are you sure you do not mean *I found out that 'kerberos method' is supported by samba 3.4* ?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, even though it is not completely trivial. I will give you [this link](http://www.tulg.org/docs/samba_ads_kerb.html) which spells it out in some detail (trust me, you will need it).

The guide is for a RHEL AS 4.0 server using Samba 3.0 (yes, exactly your version). The list of packages used is the following:

> samba-common-3.0.10-1.4E.2
>
> samba-client-3.0.10-1.4E.2
>
> samba-3.0.10-1.4E.2
>
> krb5-libs-1.3.4-17
>
> pam_krb5-2.1.8-1
>
> krb5-workstation-1.3.4-17

Explicit configuration files are given. Hope this helps.